# I am unable to login with email or contact number using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to login with email or contact no but unfortunately i am unable to login with contact number please help me how can i resolve that ? thanks.

**Note :-** I want to login with email or contact number.

**login Controller**

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

      if ($request->username) {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->username)->first();
       } else if ($request->username) {
        $user = User::where('contact_no', $request->username)- 
        >first();
       }


        if ($user ? Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) : null) {
            $temp_login_code = Hash::make(Str::random(100));
            $user->temp_login_code = $temp_login_code;
            $user->update();

            $url = config('property.cms_login_url') . '?code=' . $temp_login_code;

            return redirect($url);
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: you're using update on the user model wrong, my answer corrects this, use save if you want to do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your query condition to this:

```
if ($request->username) {
    $user = User::where('email', $request->username)
                ->orWhere('contact_no', $request->username)
                ->first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

done, Though no idea why you are making temp login codes.

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $key = (strpos($request->username, '@') !== false) ? 'email' : 'contact_no';
        if (Auth::attempt([$key => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $temp_login_code = Hash::make(Str::random(100));
            $user->update([
                'temp_login_code' => $temp_login_code,
            ]);
    
            $url = config('property.cms_login_url') . '?code=' . $temp_login_code;

            return redirect($url);
        }
        
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```